# Switch between audio and video tags in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webrtc

Is there a way to switch between the audio and video tags in HTML5 on the fly?
Meaning that if the same source starts with video and selects "video off", the source will be copied over to the audio tag and resume playing. Same thing with the other way around.

Comment: What do you have do far and what have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Sure - just pause whatever's playing, set the `<source>` on the element you want to start, and set the new player to begin where the other left off:

```js
var playing = "video";

var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
var video = document.getElementById("video");

var source = document.createElement("source");
source.setAttribute("src", "http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4");
source.setAttribute("id", "sourceElement");

video.appendChild(source);

video.play();

document.getElementById("toggleAV").onclick = function(e) {
  switch (playing) {
    case "video":
      video.pause();
      video.setAttribute("class", "hidden");
      video.removeChild(source);
      audio.appendChild(source);
      audio.currentTime = video.currentTime;
      audio.setAttribute("class", "");
      audio.play();
      playing = "audio";
      break;
    case "audio":
      audio.pause();
      audio.setAttribute("class", "hidden");
      audio.removeChild(source);
      video.appendChild(source);
      video.currentTime = audio.currentTime;
      video.setAttribute("class", "");
      video.play();
      playing = "video";
      break;
  }
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>so</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
</head>

<body>

  <video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls></video>
  <audio id="audio" controls class="hidden"></audio>
  <button id="toggleAV">Toggle AV</button>

</body>

</html>
```